# Android, Output Json data parsing to Gson Library through VO object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I want to make it easier to output structured Json data in Android.
So I created a VO object using the Gson library.
However, it did not work as expected.
The result value of log 1 and log 2 are different.
I can't figure out why to get serialized using the get method.
Can you tell me what went wrong?

The code is below.

[VO Object]

```
public class PushToday {
  @SerializedName("push_lbs_stop")
  private String push_lbs_stop;

  public String getPush_lbs_stop() {
    return push_lbs_stop;
  }

  public void setPush_lbs_stop(String push_lbs_stop) {
    this.push_lbs_stop = push_lbs_stop;
  }
}
```

[Output Code]

```
public class Output {
   public void outputJson(){
      PushToday pushToday = new PushToday();
      pushToday.setPush_lbs_stop("Y");

      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
      Log.e(TAG,"1: "+gson.toJson(pushToday));

      pushToday.getPush_lbs_stop();
      Log.e(TAG,"2: "+gson.toJson(pushToday));
   }
}
```

[Result Log]

```
1: {}
2: {"push_lbs_stop": "Y"}
```

Comment: Does your output code also belong to the same class `PushToday`?

Comment: I'm sorry. The class definition is invalid.
The two classes are independent classes.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works fine for me. Is it actually just this?